# Linking separate program parts with conflicting internal symbols into one executable

Tags: c, linker

I am working on a microcontroller project where two cores communicate over some shared memory.
Now I am tasked to create a desktop build for this project to debug and test code faster.

General procedure is straightforward: stub the hardware-specific functions, replace shared memory by a preallocated array, write a main that simulates startup calls.
All of this is already done and I now have two static libraries, one for each core. The problems start when linking the executable.

**The problem:** Both cores have some functions with the same names but different content, resulting in one core linking against the code of the other core. Sadly, simply changing the function names is not an option.

**Current Idea:** I guess what I would need is a way to link, where the code of each core prefers to link against "its own symbols", before linking against all other symbols...

Can you **(1)** help me or **(2)** point me in a different direction if this is not possible?

Additional constraints: must use clang for compilation, must be one executable in the end

Comment: Can't you just have two seperate executables?

Comment: You may want to research `objcopy --redefine-sym`.

Comment: @kaylum: no it must be one executable in the end :(

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: thanks, will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. for pointing me into the right direction.

I was able to successfully build and execute by extending my build chain with a simple script that does the following:

1. take the static libraries of both cores and run `objdump -t` on them to extract the symbol tables
2. extract all global symbols from both tables
3. compute the set intersection to get all symbols that occur in both archives
4. write a mapping file to be used by `objcopy --redefine-syms` and execute the command to rewrite the symbols in one of the libs